# Javascript adding multiple images using jsPDF the first canvas is repeated

Tags: javascript

I am using chart.js to produce some graphs and jsPDF.js to produce a report containing images of the graphs and outputting as a PDF. I loop through the canvas's containing the graphs and add to the PDF doc but it is simply repeating the same chart on each graph.

I have a button with an onclick call this function

```
function exporttopdf() {

  var doc = new jsPDF();

  var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas");

  for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {

    var currentcanvas = canvases[i];
    var url_base64jp = currentcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    doc.addImage(url_base64jp, 'png', 15, 40, 180, 160, '', 'FAST');
    doc.addPage();
  }

  doc.save('output.pdf')
}
```

When I browse the pdf the first chart is repeated many times. If I change line

```
doc.addImage(url_base64jp, 'png', 15, 40, 180, 160,'','FAST');
```

to

```
doc.addImage(url_base64jp, 'png', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

It works but the pdf created is 100mb+ as opposed to ~100kb I think the additional processing required to add the large image slows it down so the base64 image generation is done by the time the next addimage is met. I think this is probably to do with callbacks and asynchronous processing but I cant get my head round it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The code is entirely synchronous. No callbacks.

Comment: Is the image repetition consistent? I mean, is it always the first canvas or the last that is repeated, for example?

Comment: Yes, always the first repeated.

Comment: see sgelb's answer [in here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1036). The empty string is used to set an alias for the image, using empty string seems to tell jsPDF to reuse the same image (same empty alias for all)

Comment: Confirmed. Use `doc.addImage(url_base64jp, 'png', 15, 40, 180, 160, i,'FAST');`

Comment: That worked a treat. Thanks Kaddath

Answer (score 0):

just add the number of image you are adding for addImage() method,

for example :

```
pdf1 = jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
width = pdf1.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
height = pdf1.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
pdf1.addImage(document.getElementById('image1'), 'PNG', 5, 5, width, height, 1, "SLOW");
pdf1.addPage(width, height);
pdf1.addImage(document.getElementById('image2'), 'PNG', 5, 5, width, height, 2, "SLOW");
pdf1.addPage(width, height);
pdf1.addImage(document.getElementById('image3'), 'PNG', 5, 5, width, height, 3, "SLOW");
```

this way add as much images you want to add;